# Flash object doesn't load in <object> accessed from other domain

Tags: html, flash, object

I have included Flash object that doesn't load in  tag on my server. The object is being accessed from other domain. It gives not found error. But if I go directly to flash Object address, it loads perfectly. Here is code,

```
<object data="http://www.261.332.captiv8online.com/animations/display/o-t?player_width=587&amp;player_height=354" type="text/html" width="598" height="460">  alt : <a href="http://261.332.captiv8online.com/animations/display/o-t?player_width=587&amp;player_height=354">Vision after 40</a></object>
```

Here is the JSfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/n8y7s/

Comment: This is most probably a cross-domain security policy. I found [this article](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/cross-domain-security-flash) looking for this topic, but you could probably find a lot of other sources on the subject

Comment: It's cross-site security built into browsers and flash. You can't load certain content from another domain. search google for "flash cross-site object loading".

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out. So, what simply can i do to fix it?